# Android-how to highlight a date in CalendarView

Tags: java, android, android-calendar, calendarview

I've been searching on several places but haven't had any luck so far. I'm trying to find a way to highlight dates in the built-in CalendarView, all I have found is alternative Calendars, but I'd prefer to use the built-in one. I appreciate any help with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find the solution? I have same problem.

Comment: Not yet, I decided to go for a project someone else did... It doesn't look beautiful but it works.

Comment: @OmarVerduzco, I know its too late... But can u share the project?